# Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

Please help me on this error and I am new to spring. So I cannot understand with this error while I am try to running Test Data Source without spring MVC web structure

```
cd F:\NetBeansProjects\SpringContactApp; "JAVA_HOME=C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_131" cmd /c "\"\"C:\\Program Files\\NetBeans 8.0.1\\java\\maven\\bin\\mvn.bat\" -Dexec.args=\"-classpath %classpath in.ezeon.capp.test.TestDataSource\" -Dexec.executable=java -Dexec.classpathScope=test -Dmaven.ext.class.path=\"C:\\Program Files\\NetBeans 8.0.1\\java\\maven-nblib\\netbeans-eventspy.jar\" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec\""
        Running NetBeans Compile On Save execution. Phase execution is skipped and output directories of dependency projects (with Compile on Save turned on) will be used instead of their jar artifacts.
        Scanning for projects...

        ------------------------------------------------------------------------
        Building SpringContactApp 1.0-SNAPSHOT
        ------------------------------------------------------------------------

        --- exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec (default-cli) @ SpringContactApp ---
        Feb 04, 2019 12:15:40 PM org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext prepareRefresh
        INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@531d72ca: startup date [Mon Feb 04 12:15:40 IST 2019]; root of context hierarchy
        Feb 04, 2019 12:15:40 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor <init>
        INFO: JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
        Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up.)
            at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:80)
            at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:619)
            at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:870)
            at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:931)
            at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:941)
            at in.ezeon.capp.test.TestDataSource.main(TestDataSource.java:23)
        Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up.)
            at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:2294)
            at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:2039)
            at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1533)
            at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:111)
            at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:77)
            ... 5 more
        Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up.
```

Below codes are SpringRootConfig.java class and TestDataSource.java class
And i am using netbeans 8 and spring framework.

```
package in.ezeon.capp.config;

import static java.lang.Boolean.TRUE;
import org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

/**
 *
 * @author admin
 */
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"in.ezeon.capp.dao"})
public class SpringRootConfig {
    //TODO: Services,DAO,DataSource,Email sender or some other business layer beans
    @Bean
    public BasicDataSource getDataSource()
    {
        BasicDataSource ds=new BasicDataSource();
        ds.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        //ds.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/capp_db?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8&useSSL=false&autoReconnect=true&failOverReadOnly=false");//localhost//127.0.0.1
        ds.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/capp_db");
        ds.setUsername("root");
        ds.setPassword("dbadmin@123");//dbadmin@123
        ds.setMaxTotal(2);
        ds.setInitialSize(1);
        ds.setTestOnBorrow(true);
        ds.setValidationQuery("SELECT 1");
        ds.setDefaultAutoCommit(TRUE);
        return ds;
    }
}
```

And also find the below screenshot for this error.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kub8d.png)

Comment: Can you connect to your database, from the same machine where this code is running, using the same credentials?

Comment: looks like network issue, your code not able to connect the DB.

Answer (score 0):

The error is related to the database connection. Check the data you're using right now. Perhaps not created database with the same name to which you connect.

Answer (score 0):

In your case:

```
 Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException:
 Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up.
```

- check your jdbc url.
- check the availability of your db (on that url, server running?, port?, database? ideally same driver, same network ..e.g with Netbeans "Services" Tab>"Databases")
- check the network/proxy/firewall, you are in.